# How does database will be made available in case of container world

Tags: database, docker, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, cloud

I am a new bee to the cloud and trying to understand few common issues which people solved already in the field.

As of now i have created a docker image for my java based web application. Also i have created a oracle database 11g XE instance with a database imported by default.  Finally i pushed these docker images to the AWS repository and deployed to EC2 instances as a docker containers. I am able to access my web application using the public IP and everything is looking good except one thing. When the EC2 instance went down or recreated for some reason, the database container will be recreated with the original database, i will be losing all the data's which have been created after setting up my application for the first time.

I know this is a common issue in the container world, i just want to know how people solve this issue.

Comment: Please read more [docs about docker storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/), maybe you would find useful things. BTW, it’s not an issue, it’s a feature.

Comment: I am not sure whether you got my question correct. Yes, we can maintain the data integrity by mounting data using the docker volume concepts in the hosts. But my question is how do i maintain the data inside the database which i am running as a docker container ? I think in Kubernetes we have a concept called statefulsets.

Comment: I think you wish to persist data in writable layer of container, which could not be done in any way.

Comment: If that is the case, no one is running database as a docker container as of now ??

Comment: Yes, there are. But I believe no one would persist data in writable layer of container, especially in production environment. Since that would make db container too big to stop/restart/migrate, even delete. Additionally, it’s really unsafe for db data. Think about somebody deleting the db container, what would that lead to? A disaster, no doubt.

Comment: If they don’t use database container for persisting data then what for they will be using database ? Just to retrieve the static data from database to show it in the screen ?  For example, companies like amazon have every service as  a micro service and each service might be in a container and those container might require database to persist data when user change something like ordering items from the website. Any idea how do they persist data in this case..?

Comment: Service containers are stateless, they record stateful data through database container. And db containers store those data by bind mount or named volumes, or both. Even the Statefulsets object in k8s you mentioned above, it does not persist data in writable layer of container. If you dig that deeper enough, you might find all based on bind mount and volumes. That’s the way how Docker persist data. It would be another case if your k8s cluster is not bases on Docker containerization, which is supported in k8s.

Comment: I know we can store data from containers using the volumes or bind mountings, but we can use the same concepts to store the data from the database container is something i am curious to know how they actually export the data from the database. Btw thanks for explaining about these concepts @Light.G, It helped